Is it possible to extract a jar from a Native Image built with GraalVM?
I've built a Native Image from a Java project that includes a licensed library (jar), as a Maven dependency. That library must not be made available to anyone. Once built into the NI, is it safe ? Or is there a possibility for someone to extract the jar from the NI ?
EDIT: the Java project that I've mentioned is much more than just the licensed jar, there are thousands of code lines, and other dependencies.
Related links (though linked to the code, not the dependencies):

It is impossible/impractical to decompile a NI and see the original code
Reverse-engineer a decompiled NI is possible but very difficult


With sufficient effort, everything is reverse-engineerable. The only way to avoid that is to not ship the code to clients at all, i.e. put it behind an API. Bytecode is already an obfuscation of source. If shipping bytecode isn't within the license terms because it's reverse-engineerable, then I don't see why shipping assembly would be, unless the license specifically states that one is okay and the other isn't.

Also it probably depends on the license. If the license doesn't allow you to include/repackage the library, you probably can't use it.

I can use the library in the context of this project. I've been asked to not make the library available to the people to whom I deliver the NI.
I can't put it behind an API neither, as a requirement.

We do not have the exact technology yet(18/04/2024), meaning there is no reverse engineering tool invented to generate java code from native image(NI) which is generated by GraalVM. Therefore we can safely say no one can generate jar from NI.
Like explained in your reference native image can turn to assembly and read the code via there. This does not mean you are sharing the jar with customers. I think it is safe to build and release NI to customers. But still this needs to be informed/discussed the owner of the library before doing the release.
